# Approximation of summation of $\log x-\log n$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I was trying to give an asymptotic calculation for $\sum_{n\leq x}(\log x-\log n)$, and the proof provided by the instructor is that
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}(\log x-\log n)=(x\log x + O(\log x))+ (x\log x+O(x))=O(x).
$$
I am okay with the second "=", but don't quite understand how the first "=" comes. Can somebody explain?

Comment: The sign in the middle should be $-$.  The sum of the first term is exactly $x \log x$, so there need not be an $O(\log x)$ (but $0 \in O(\log x)$ so this is true)

Comment: @RossMillikan Maybe $x$ might not be an integer?

Comment: @angryavian:  when I see sum indices I presume they are naturals unless otherwise stated.  I suppose it could be.

Comment: According to the comments, it is left to show that $\sum_{n\leq x}\log n=x\log x+O(x)$. Does partial summation do the trick?

Comment: @Christina You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to handle that term.

Comment: @angryavian Stirling's approximation is not needed for that. Partial summation itself can give that asymptotic formula

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n\le x}(\log x-\log n)=\lfloor x\rfloor\log x-\sum_{n\le x}\log n
$$

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor=x+\mathcal O(1)$, we have $\lfloor x\rfloor\log x=\log x+\mathcal O(\log x)$. Now it remains to expand the last term. By partial summation, we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le x}\log n
&=\int_1^x\log t\mathrm dt-\{x\}\log x+\int_1^x{\{t\}\over t}\mathrm dx \\
&=[t\log t-t]_1^x+\mathcal O(\log x)+\mathcal O\left(\int_1^x{\mathrm dt\over t}\right) \\
&=x\log x-x+\mathcal O(\log x)
\end{aligned}

Combining everything gives

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le x}(\log x-\log n)
&=x\log x+\mathcal O(\log x)-[x\log x-x+\mathcal O(\log x) \\
&=x+\mathcal O(\log x)=\mathcal O(x)
\end{aligned}